# Print out unique elements in an array with C language?

Tags: arrays, c

Problem: Print out unique elements from an array.
Example: We have {1,2,3,2,4,5,5,6], the result will be {1,2,3,4,5,6}.

I can only manage to print out {1,3,4,6}. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int a[], int n);
void show(int a[], int n);

int main()
{
  int n, i;
  printf("Enter number of elements: "); scanf("%d", &n);
  int a[n];
  input(a,n);
  printf("\nArray before change!\n");
  show(a,n);
  printf("\n----------------------------------------");
  printf("\nArray after change!\n");

  int b[101];
  for(i=0; i<101; i++)
      {
        b[i] = 0;
      }
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        b[a[i]]++;
      }

  for(i=0; i < n; i++)
      {
        int j = 0;
        if (b[a[i]] == 1)
            {
              printf("%d ", a[i]);
            }
      }
return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void input(int a[], int n)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < n; i++)
      {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
      }
}
void show(int a[], int n)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < n; i++)
      {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
      }
}
```

In the above codes, I use array b[] as a counter to count presence of each element. I stuck at the point that I cannot print the elements-that-appear-more-than-once. Do you have any idea to crack this ? I thank you.

Comment: `if (b[a[i]] == 1)` -> `if (b[a[i]] >= 1)`

Comment: This will result different from the example because this will print out all the elements in the array

Comment: Why would it? All the other `b` values should be 0. That's the main point of the algorithm. No? Did you try it?

Comment: If it is ">=1" instead of  "==1", it will also print out the element  n time (n is the counter for presence of that element). But can you think of any better idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: @QuanLeAnh You do need to check `if (b[a[i]] >= 1)`, and then set `b[a[i]] = 0;` when the condition is true. In fact, the `b` array doesn't need to count the number of occurrences. It just needs to be 1 if the number is in the array, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Your current solution prints elements which appears only one time instead of all unique elements. for example in array(1,2,3,2,4,5,5,6) 2 and 5 appear more than one time and thus not in your final answer. So instead of initializing the counter array before, try to update it as you traverse the array and print the element when its count is 1 and skip when count becomes greater than 1.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int b[101];`  the max number of duplicates is `n` /2  where does `101` enter the logic?  Or is there a crfitieria that you didn't mention that no data item can be greater than 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void input(int a[], int n);
void show(int a[], int n);

int main(){
  int i=0,j,k=0,n;
  int a[10];
  int b[10];
  printf("Enter number of elements: "); //number of elements you want to store.
  scanf("%d", &n);
  input(a,n);
  printf("\nArray before change!\n");
  show(a,n);

  //removing duplicate elements from array.
    for(i=0; i<n ; i++){
        for(j=i-1 ; j>=0 ; j--)
            if(a[j]==a[i])
                goto down;
        b[k++] = a[i];  // storing unique elements in array b.
        down: ;
    }
    
  printf("\n----------------------------------------");
  printf("\nArray after change!\n");
  show(b , k);
return 0;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void input(int a[], int n){
  for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}

void show(int a[], int n){
  for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```